# Can't upload to a specific folder getting 503 error

Tags: c#, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am trying to upload a simple text file to a specific folder in google documents but with no luck.

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\test.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open);
DocumentEntry lastUploadEntry = 
    globalData.service.UploadDocument("c:\\test.txt", null);                                                                               

string feed =
    "https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full/folder%folder:0B2dzFB6YvN-kYTRlNmNhYjEtMTVmNC00ZThkLThiMjQtMzFhZmMzOGE2ZWU1/contents/";

var result = 
    globalData.service.Insert(new Uri(feed), fileStream, "application/pdf", "test");
```

I get an error saying

> "The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable."

I am suspecting that the destination folders uri is wrong but i can't figure out the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a complete sample at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#uploading_a_new_document_or_file_with_both_metadata_and_content that uses the resumable upload component:

```
using System;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Client.ResumableUpload;
using Google.GData.Documents;

namespace MyDocumentsListIntegration
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      DocumentsService service = new DocumentsService("MyDocumentsListIntegration-v1");

      // TODO: Instantiate an Authenticator object according to your authentication
      // mechanism (e.g. OAuth2Authenticator).
      // Authenticator authenticator =  ...

      // Instantiate a DocumentEntry object to be inserted.
      DocumentEntry entry = new DocumentEntry();

      // Set the document title
      entry.Title.Text = "Legal Contract";

      // Set the media source
      entry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("c:\\contract.txt", "text/plain");

      // Define the resumable upload link
      Uri createUploadUrl = new Uri("https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full");
      AtomLink link = new AtomLink(createUploadUrl.AbsoluteUri);
      link.Rel = ResumableUploader.CreateMediaRelation;
      entry.Links.Add(link);

      // Set the service to be used to parse the returned entry
      entry.Service = service;

      // Instantiate the ResumableUploader component.
      ResumableUploader uploader = new ResumableUploader();

      // Set the handlers for the completion and progress events
      uploader.AsyncOperationCompleted += new AsyncOperationCompletedEventHandler(OnDone);
      uploader.AsyncOperationProgress += new AsyncOperationProgressEventHandler(OnProgress);

      // Start the upload process
      uploader.InsertAsync(authenticator, entry, new object());
    }

    static void OnDone(object sender, AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) {
        DocumentEntry entry = e.Entry as DocumentEntry;
    }

    static void OnProgress(object sender, AsyncOperationProgressEventArgs e) {
        int percentage = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the article [Google Apps Platform Uploading documents](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#creating_or_uploading_text_documents)

 Also check out [Google Documents List API version 3.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#getting_a_resource_entry_again)

 Uri should be something similar to below:

```
string feed = @"https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#getting_a_resource_entry_again"; 
//it may not be exact, just check and read from the links
```

Comment: Can you please tell me if the feed uri is correct?I am suspecting that is the problem.

Comment: I am not sure, Error 503 is service unavailable, http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E503.html

Comment: Ok.I really appreciate your help.Take care.

Answer (score 1):

Try this uri:

```
"https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/folder%3A" + fRid + "/contents"
```

//fRid is the Resource Id of the folder.. in your case: 0B2dzFB6YvN-kYTRlNmNhYjEtMTVmNC00ZThkLThiMjQtMzFhZmMzOGE2ZWU1

Also I guess your URI is giving this error because you are using folder resource ID as - folder:resourceID

Try removing **folder:** and use only RID

Code to cutout "folder:" -

```
int ridIndex = dRid.IndexOf(":");
Rid = Rid.Substring(ridIndex + 1);
```